# Assign names to index elements in large list - R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

Is it possible to rename a list of lists elements?

For example:

```
fast <- subset.data.frame(mtcars, mtcars$hp > 250)
medium <- subset.data.frame(mtcars, mtcars$hp >200 & mtcars$hp < 300)
slow <- subset.data.frame(mtcars, mtcars$hp < 80)
mycars <- list(fast, medium, slow)
```

Gives a `List of 3`

```
mycars

[[1]]
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Ford Pantera L 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.17 14.5  0  1    5    4
Maserati Bora  15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8

[[2]]
                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Duster 360          14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Camaro Z28          13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4

[[3]]
                mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7 62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7 52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0 66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
```

But I would like to rename the index `[[1]] [[2]] [[3]]` as `[[fast]] [[medium]] [[slow]]`, OR **preferable** keep the index and also add the individual names of the list as an additional descriptor.  Something like: `[[1]]"Fast"`

Scrolling through stackoverflow, similiar questions suggest renaming with `names`, but `names(mycars)` returns NULL.

```
names(mycars[[1]]) 
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

But I'm not interested in changing the column names.

This works:

```
 mycars <- list(fast = fast, medium = medium, slow = slow)
```

But, my actual dataset is more complicated, and I'm hoping to be able to rename the  elements *after* creating the list.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mycars <- setNames(mycars,c("fast","medium","slow"))
```

you can still use indexes :

```
mycars[[1]]
mycars[["fast"]]
```

`names(mycars[[1]])` returns the column names of `mycars[[1]]`.

One thing that might be counterintuitive is that a list in `R` has an optional `names` attribute of the same length as the number of columns, but the column items don't have their name attached to them (there's no singular `name` attribute).

By the time you call `mycars[[1]]` you lost the names. If you call `mycars[1]` however you get a list of one element only, and this list can have a `names` attribute of length one.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Very counter intuitive!. Indeed calling names(mycars[]) gives a list of all named ("fast", "medium", "slow") items.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the names using the function names, for example:

```
names(data)[1:2] <- c("january", "february")
```

Comment: Not sure why, I just used your example, with the mycars data and it worked.